# how thread object gets created in activity class and main thread creation

Tags: android, multithreading

i m now saw about threads.I have created a thread object in activity class.I got confused how  without extending or importing the thread class, thread objects gets created. and i have read in dev. site that main thread gets automatically created when the android application gets started. i didnt understand the concept..please explain

Comment: Take some time to read [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers) . Any further questions, write here with what you have worked so far. Thanks.

Comment: thankyou for that tutorial...i understand the concept but what i m still confusing is how the new thread object gets created without extending or importing the thread class.??

Comment: Is you confusion about the main Thread getting created or any other random Thread. If you could update your question with where you have seen the problem, it would be helpful.

Comment: i got confused in this line: new Thread(new Runnable()....); how this new thread object gets created?? without importing or extending the thread class..??